# Weird event behavior in a Popup inside a DataGridColumnHeader

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

I'm not using any external libraries here, just plain WPF.

I have a DataGrid with a custom DataGridColumnHeader. This column header contains a ToggleButton to toggle a Popup. Inside the popup there is a TextBox. The problem I'm having is that doubleclicking inside the TextBox raises the MouseDoubleClick event on the DataGrid. Here's a simplified version containing numbered comments I will refer to afterwards

```
<Window x:Class="PopupsAreWeird.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PopupsAreWeird" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <!-- 1) This eventhandler is never called -->
                        <Grid Control.MouseDoubleClick="Grid_MouseDoubleClick_1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" />
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="openToggle" Grid.Column="1" Content="Open" />

                            <Popup IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=openToggle, Path=IsChecked}" StaysOpen="True">
                                <!-- 2) This eventhandler is always called, and the problem I am having is there regardless of whether I set e.Handled = true in this handler or not -->
                                <TextBox Width="200" MouseDoubleClick="TextBox_MouseDoubleClick" />
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <!-- 3) This eventhandler is always called, but never should be -->
        <DataGrid MouseDoubleClick="DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header 1" Width="200" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

1) I do not understand why this handler is never called. This was meant to set e.Handled to true to stop bubbling upwards to the DataGrid. While Grid does not have a definition for MouseDoubleClick, it is my understanding that I can attach eventhandlers for any event to any element (like attaching ButtonBase.Click to a Panel element). Is this not true, or is there any special case here I am missing?

3) I want to avoid the double click event bubbling to here, but even if I set e.Handled to true in eventhandler 2, this eventhandler is called, and in that handler, e.Handled is false. I assume the reason is that the Popup is defined inside of DataGridColumnHeader, and for some weird reason 2 events are being raised, one for the tree of the popup, and one for the tree that contains the Popup element, but that seems a bit nonsensical.

I know Popup is a sort of weird thing in WPF, but this seems like I'm missing something obvious. Is there any way to achieve what I want, i.e. not have events (or at least the MouseDoubleClick event) bubble up to the DataGrid?

Thanks in advance,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You are right, You can attach a handler for a routed event to any `UIElement`. But indeed the `Popup` is a special case. The `Popup` is a special control that behaves like `Window`. It can popup everywhere on the screen, always rendered top-most and is not necessarily bound to the application itself. That's why its visual tree is detached from the application's visual tree. `Popup.Child` will be a separate isolated visual tree. [Microsoft Docs: Popup and the Visual Tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/popup-overview#popup-and-the-visual-tree).
Since routed events traverse the visual tree to be handled by any node, it makes sense that bubbling/tunneling routed events inside the `Popup` will stop/start at the root of this isolated tree. So routed events that are originated in the `Popup` cannot be handled outside the `Popup`.

3) Short version: `Control.MouseDoubleClick` (and the preview version) is a special event that behaves different. This event is raised on each `UIElement` on the route when the event traverses the visual tree. So setting `Handled` to `true` has no effect.
To solve your problem, you should either handle `UIElement.PreviewMousLeftButtonDown` and check if the `MouseButtonEventArgs.ClickCount` equals `2` to detect a double click and then set `Handled = true`
or check if the type of the `sender` or `RoutedEventArgs.Source` is not `TextBox` before handling it (explicit event filtering).

> "Although this routed event seems to follow a bubbling route through
>   an element tree, it actually is a direct routed event that is raised
>   along the element tree by each `UIElement`. If you set the `Handled`
>   property to `true` in a `MouseDoubleClick` event handler, subsequent
>   `MouseDoubleClick` events along the route will occur with `Handled` set to
>   `false`. This is a higher-level event for control consumers who want to
>   be notified when the user double-clicks the control and to handle the
>   event in an application.
>
> Control authors who want to handle mouse double clicks should use the
>   `MouseLeftButtonDown` event when `ClickCount` is equal to two. This will
>   cause the state of `Handled` to propagate appropriately in the case
>   where another element in the element tree handles the event.
>
> The `Control` class defines the `PreviewMouseDoubleClick` and
>   `MouseDoubleClick` events, but not corresponding single-click events. To
>   see if the user has clicked the control once, handle the `MouseDown`
>   event (or one of its counterparts) and check whether the `ClickCount`
>   property value is `1`."
>   [Microsoft Docs: Control.MouseDoubleClick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control.mousedoubleclick?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! I somehow missed this part in the documentation, thanks for pointing that out. I will try it out once I get back to it later today. I do have a clarifying question though. Points 1 and 3 seem to be mutually exclusive in your reply. If events inside a Popup Control never bubble outside the Popup (as would be understandable and is the explanation for eventhandler 1), why is eventhandler 3 called? This is also outside the Popup. Both are the MouseDoubleClick event as well, so if this is a special case, shouldn't it be the same for both?

Comment: I got around to it earlier than expected, and it does indeed work, so I'm already marking it as an answer since the original question has been answered. If you know the answer to the follow up question though it would be greatly appreciated if you could provide that as well

Comment: This is a special event that "artificially" traverses the visual tree. The event is _created_ on each `UIElement`. There is no real visual tree traversal like `this.GetVisualParent().RaiseEvent(e)`. The `Popup.Child` tree is still connected to the `Popup` as logical tree. So the engine apparently traverses the logical tree and visits each nodes content or sub-tree. Since `Popup.Child` is marked as content property, the engine would identify it as possible sub-tree. This routed event is special. It's a pseudo routed event that wraps up a `ClickCount` check of `(Preview)MouseLeftButtonDown`.

Comment: The proof that `Popup.Child` is detached from the application's visual tree: [Microsoft Docs: Popup and the Visual Tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/popup-overview#popup-and-the-visual-tree).

Comment: `MouseDoubleClick` traversing the logical instead of the visual tree (therefore not being raised on the `Grid`) and the `Popup` being a logical child of the containing element makes a lot of sense, thanks for clarifying.